# Sharepoint 2013 Adding a add new event link in content editor

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013

I would like to add a "Add New Event" link in a content editor web part to the calendar page. When clicked should open the default "new event" window to add an event. How can do that? what should be the link look like?

Thanks
Ganesh

Answer (score 0):

If you want to open the form in the whole page, the link should be like this:

```html
<a href="<weburl>/Lists/<calendarlist>/NewForm.aspx">Add New Event</a>
```

To open in a modal dialog:

```js
function openDialog() {

    var url = "<weburl>/Lists/<calendarlist>/NewForm.aspx";
    var options = {
        title: "Add New Event",
        width: 400,
        height: 600,
        url: url
    };

    SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
}
```

```html
<a href="#" onclick="openDialog()">Add New Event</a>
```

Overwrite `<weburl>` with the web relative url and `<calendarlist>` with the relative url of the list (most of times the list name)
Example: https://mysiteurl/Lists/Calendar/NewForm.aspx

Answer (score 0):

1. In a site page, click edit page and click on Add a Web Part.
2. Select your calendar list from Apps section in Categories.
3. Once your calendar is in your Site Page, click Add a Web Part again.
4. Select Content Editor Web part from Media and Contents section.
5. Inside Content Editor webpart  click on "Click here to add new Contents"
6. From the ribbon, click on "Edit source".
   [enter image description here][1]
7. Type or paste following code:

`<a href="webUrl/Lists/Calendar/NewForm.aspx">Add New Event</a>`

8. Lastly Click on Save page.